# Teradata - Add dates as a new column into an existing table

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

In Teradata, I have a table full of calendar dates, and I have another table full of Customer IDs.  I want to add all calendar dates into the Customer table, so that every Customer has a row for every date that exists in the Calendar table.  Please can someone walk me through how to do this?

Calendar table (yyyy-mm-dd):

```
| Date |
| ---- |
|2024-01-01|
|2024-01-02|
|2024-01-03|
|2024-01-04|
|2024-01-05|
|2024-01-06|
...etc...
```

Customer table:

```
| ID | Name | Country |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
|103| Daffy Duck | Spain |
|104| Donald Duck | Spain |
|105| Tom Cat | UK |
|106| Jerry Mouse | UK |
...etc...
```

The Customer table needs to look like:

```
|Date | ID | Name | Country |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
|2024-01-01|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|2024-01-02|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|2024-01-03|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|2024-01-04|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|2024-01-05|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|2024-01-06|101| Mickey Mouse | France |
|2024-01-01|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
|2024-01-02|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
|2024-01-03|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
|2024-01-04|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
|2024-01-05|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
|2024-01-06|102| Minnie Mouse | France |
...etc...
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM customer CROSS JOIN calendar ORDER BY ID, Date`

Answer (score 0):

As shown by user dnoeth the answer is simply:
SELECT * FROM customer CROSS JOIN calendar ORDER BY ID, Date